# Which AC-3 algorithm is being used here?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, constraint-programming

[image: AC-3 with 4-queen]

This is the illustration of the AC-3 algorithm for four queens from [*exhaustive study of essential constraint satisfaction problem techniques based on N-Queens problem*](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICCITECHN.2017.8281850) by Md. Ahsan Ayub, Kazi A Kalpoma, Humaira Tasnim Proma, Syed Mehrab Kabir and Rakib Ibna Hamid.

I am confused whether this is pure AC-3 or AC-3 with backtracking. Which one is it?

Comment: https://ucsmmm-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/thuriyathwin_ucsm_edu_mm/ETH58l4-qE1Hj5wptIPE0p0B7eGHY3_MuNIZ1RCjQCswZg?e=gTRJX4

Answer (score 1):

The Fig. 5 in the question depicts AC-algorithm with backtracking.

In fact, without backtracking, checking arc-consistency alone can hardly solve the 4-Queen problem. Unless it happens that choices made so far will be extended to a desired configuration, any algorithm to solve CSP have to backtrack so as to check other possibilities.

Here is a relevant excerpt from the article.

> Conversely, if it does not become possible to place a Queen at  the  pointed  column,  like  in  Fig. 5(c),  **backtracker  will backtrack**  the  previous  assigned  Queen’s  column  to  reassign the conflicted Queen to a newly safe cell at the same column. Then, it will, at first, clear the constraints it created by calling the implemented modular function.

Comment: if so,this article is used the algorithm of https://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/constraints/propagation.html ,is it? @Apass.Jack

Comment: Not sure what you meant (your sentence seems broken). If you meant that that articles also explains the idea that backtracking goes hand in hand with (arc) consistency checking, yes.

Comment: if so,the pseudo code in fig5 is [procedure AC3-BT(cv)
  Q <- {(Vi,Vcv) in arcs(G),i<cv};
  consistent <- true;
  while not Q empty & consistent
    select and delete any arc (Vk,Vm) from Q;
    consistent <- REVISE(Vk,Vm)
  endwhile
  return consistent
end AC3-BT]

Comment: The pure AC-3 algorithm puts all arcs in queue.If AC-3 combines with backtracking ,how to put arcs in queue?

Comment: Write the variable assignments with backtracking mechanism as pseudocode or programming code first. Then add AC3 as another procedure to that.

Comment: I have written it but the output is similar with MAC-3 not like in fig5.